# The shortest periodic geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry

For $a \gt 0$, surface of revolution $S_a$ is defined by
$(\sqrt{a^2+z^2}\cos \theta,\sqrt{a^2+z^2}\sin \theta,z)$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi, -\infty \lt z \lt \infty$

How can I find the shortest periodic geodesic on $S_a$?

 Is it unique?

Comment: Can you visualize the picture? There is an obvious candidate.

Comment: You mean $(acos \theta, asin \theta, 0)$?